# Does Church Turing Thesis guarantee that recursive code can be implemented into as an iterative implementation?

Tags: recursion, iteration, time-complexity, complexity-theory

I remember hearing and reading how the Church-Turing thesis can guarantee that a recursive implementation of code can be done in an iterative approach and vice versa. Is this really true? I am unable to see so if so. Maybe I am misunderstanding the Turing Thesis, from a beginner coder's persepctihves I am not quite able to understand the thesis. If this thesis does make such guarantee, would this also make the guarantee for both approaches (iterative and recursive) both to have same worst case time complexity? I know that usually or always both ways will have same running time, but recursive will have more constant overhead, but does this thesis guarantee this?

Answer (score 1):

The Church-Turing Thesis says exactly one thing, namely that our intuitive notion of computability and our mathematical notion of computability are the same.

That's it.

That's a philosophical statement, it has nothing to do with programming. It most certainly has nothing to do with iterative vs. recursive implementations of code.

Comment: This may be pedantically accurate, but ignores significant developments around the Church-Turing Thesis. The lambda calculus (Church & Kleene), Turing machines (Turing), and general recursive functions (Godel & Herbrand) have been formally proven to be equivalent (cf. work by Kleene and Turing). 

In practical terms, this means that the set of procedures expressible through recursion (Godel/Church) are equivalent to the set of procedures expressible through iterative computation (Turing).

So AIUI, yes, all iterative programs can be expressed recursively, and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

An iterative loop or a function are concepts created by the programming language and they are compiled down to jumps and data structures. Because of this I can tell you right away that any recursive function can be rewritten as a loop.

If we then look at the nature of a function. Eg. in SICP you often hear they use the term recursive process. What that means is that if you walk a binary tree that is inherently a recursive process and the only way to do it in a loop is if you store the the data needed to backtrack in the same manner as a recursive function would.

Likewise if you have a recursive function where the recursive call is in tail position it is an iterative process. Eg. you could easily rewrite it as a loop from the beginning to the recursive call with just manipulating the variables before it continues.

Thus. A recursive or iterative function are just mere methods we use, while we cannot change an algorithm that does a recursive process to become an iterative one.